# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input: Typo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with this statement? Keeps producing error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. I presume it's because the variable is over 80 characters in length is that correct? I ask because I've read that there's a limit of 80 characters to a varname, however I've also read that chrome allows for up to 500 in varname lengths.

Code is simply javascript/jquery.

Code:
    `var Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_File_Close_rect =
$(".Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_File_Close_class")[0].getBoundingClientRect();`

Also, it is not returning the value of `[0].getBoundingClientRect()` for variable: `Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_File_Close_rect`.

**UPDATE:**  Needed more code.

```
<div id="Company_Fs_Section_Buttons_FileMenu"class="Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent"style="position:absolute;
width:200;
display:grid;
">
<button id="ButtonId"class="Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos_class"onclick="Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos("Company_Fs_Pages_Admin");
    ">Videos</button>

var Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos_rect=$(".Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos_class")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

function Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos(varname1){var varname2=$(".Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_FileName_var").text();
$.ajax({data:{Page:varname1,FileName:varname2},type:"POST",url:url_root + "Company/Fs/Sections/Buttons/FileMenu/AddContent/Videos.php",success:function (data){$(".modal").css({"display":"inline-block"});
$(".modal_mid").html("<pre>" + data + "</pre>");
script=$(data).text();
$.globalEval(script);
alert(data);
}});
}
```

Comment: Please don't downvote an honest question. This code still didn't work for a reason, and others might find this useful.

Comment: I get the error when clicking the button. Else, the error doesn't display.

Comment: Your code and explanations are all over the place, you should put more effort when asking questions on SO, -1. Like for example: well structured paragraphs, code samples which are clear (minimal verifiable and complete examples), using code beautifiers and then paste the code, etc. small things but really important at the same time. P.S. I noticed that your other questions are basically the same.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try. I have to admit there's a lot of rules that aren't explained. Getting downvoted in our hamilton programming community is an often occurrence. Perhaps SO could be clearer on the charter/goal of questions it's trying to have submitted. Example: Ask a question in a manner that future question searchers can easily adapt to their own code, Example: Here's a few question formats to choose from, Example: What we will downvote and why, etc. It's so easy for newbs to get downvoted that after a few tries newbs are blocked from asking questions. Could be modified.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You have a syntax error in your HTML.  If you want to use quotes inside quotes, either escape them, or use inner single quotes inside your outer double quotes (or vice versa).

In this line, specifically:

```
<button id="ButtonId"class="Company_Fs_Pages_Admin___Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos_class"onclick="Company_Fs_Sections_Buttons_FileMenu_AddContent_Videos('Company_Fs_Pages_Admin');
    ">Videos</button>
```

Use single quotes around `'Company_Fs_Pages_Admin'` instead of double quotes.

So, be more careful next time, StackOverflow is not here to fix your typos.

Comment: Oh thanks. Sorry I found it was because I had `display:none` on the class element, therefore the value from [0].getBoundingClientRect() returned neg. Cheers.

Comment: I updated my question with more code as I'm getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: @jasperasd I edited my answer as per the new code you provided. As it turns out, yes, it's a typo in your HTML.